# Cloud Messaging (Push notifications)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cloud, firebase-console

I have been trying to send out push notifications to ONLY non-purchasers, but it continues to include the purchasers.

In this context "purchasers" is anyone who has done an IAP in my iOS app.

The steps I follow is in cloud messaging I select target as:

Targeting

User Audience does not include all of Purchasers

But still the purchasers receive the push.

Comment: If you're having problems with the way the Firebase console works, please contact Firebase support directly.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Hey Greg. It's a bit hard to follow what you've done in pure text. Can you add some screenshots to your question of what you've done in the Firebase console?